# Integrate solvemedia captcha using perl

Tags: perl, captcha

I would like to know how do I insert solvemedia captcha with my script. I did install the module from their site (https://portal.solvemedia.com/media/download/WWW-SolveMedia-1.1.tar.gz) but don't know where to add this (their instructions):

Once the plugin is installed, you can start making calls to the Solve Media API.
**Display the Widget**

To display the Solve Media widget on one of your forms, instantiate the SolveMedia class, supplying it with your API keys. Then call the get_html function. You can find your API keys at My account:

```
use WWW::SolveMedia;
my $c = WWW::SolveMedia->new( 'my challenge key',
            'my verification key',
            'my hash key' );

# output widget
print $c->get_html();
```

**Process Answer**

You can check the user's response by calling SolveMedia.check_answer(...).

```
# check answer
my $result = $c->check_answer( $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}, $challenge, $response );

if( $result->{is_valid} ){
    print "Yay!";
}else{
    print "Dang it :-(\n";
    print "Error: ".$result->{error};
}
```

And this is where I get stuck, cos I don't have a clue how/where to insert that code. If anyone of you is willing to help, please respond. I'm willing to pay a few bucks.

Answer (score 1):

You create the new object, and either save the results of get_html into a variable which you then stick into some web page, or you print it inline.

You put the Perl code in the subroutines that generate the pages that you want the captcha to appear.
and you put the call to process in the code that process the submission of the form on the page that you printed the captcha into.